# how to create events on facebook with facebook api 2020?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

is it possible to create facebook events with the help of `facebook sdk` or `api`?

I have read that it used to be possible in the past and now with `v6.0` it is not anymore.

Is there another way to write a script that takes care of this?

i would like to work with `python` or `js` for this.

does anyone know about this?

Comment: No, that is currently not possible, there is no API for this. (And anything else, using automation tools, Selenium, etc., would be against Facebook’s ToS to begin with.)

Comment: are u 100% sure about that?

Comment: Yes, I am. The API documentation explicitly says it is not possible as well.